# how can add new key and it's value in Javascript json variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Suppose that I have a variable user and I need to append a new question as a key and its value to that newly created id

**users variable**

```
const  users= {
      johndoe: {
        answers:{
            "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": "optionTwo",
            "vthrdm985a262al8qx3do": "optionTwo",
            "xj352vofupe1dqz9emx13r": "optionOne"
        }
       
      },
     joseph: {
        answers:{
            "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": "optionTwo",
            
        }
       
      }
      
}
```

**New key and its value and the user who answered the question**

```
const questionId = "thisisnewkey";
const newQuestionAnswer = "optionTwo";
const userWhoAnsweredTheQuestion = "joseph";
```

Before appending a question and its answer its mandatory to find the user who answered that question
**Expected output**

```
const  users= {
      johndoe: {
        answers:{
            "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": "optionTwo",
            "vthrdm985a262al8qx3do": "optionTwo",
            "xj352vofupe1dqz9emx13r": "optionOne"
        }

      },
     joseph: {
        answers:{
            "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": "optionTwo",
             "thisisnewkey":"optionTwo"


        }

      }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bracket notation (`[]`) for dynamic property of the object:

```
users[userWhoAnsweredTheQuestion].answers[questionId] = newQuestionAnswer;
```

```js
const  users= {
      johndoe: {
        answers:{
            "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": "optionTwo",
            "vthrdm985a262al8qx3do": "optionTwo",
            "xj352vofupe1dqz9emx13r": "optionOne"
        }
       
      },
     joseph: {
        answers:{
            "6ni6ok3ym7mf1p33lnez": "optionTwo",
            
        }
       
      }
      
} 

const questionId = "thisisnewkey";
const newQuestionAnswer = "optionTwo";
const userWhoAnsweredTheQuestion = "joseph";

users[userWhoAnsweredTheQuestion].answers[questionId] = newQuestionAnswer;

console.log(users);
```

Comment: Objects stored in variables declared with `const` can be edited just fine, the variable can just not be completely reassigned to another object.

Answer (score 0):

By using ES6 code should be

```
 ...users,
       [userWhoAnsweredTheQuestion]:{
          ...users[userWhoAnsweredTheQuestion],
              answers: {
              ...users[userWhoAnsweredTheQuestion].answers,
                [questionId]: answer
                    }
                }
```